# Реализация аналогичного меню

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Подскажите, как сверстать [вот такое меню](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_34740/index.html)?
В том коде, который там на сайте, что-то не могу разобраться...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А я схитрил: http://jsfiddle.net/WgPvd/

CSS:

```
/**
 * How to make 3-corner-rounded triangle in CSS (SO)
 * https://stackoverflow.com/q/14446677/1397351
 */
.triangle, .triangle:before, .triangle:after { 
    width: 250px; 
    height: 250px; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    transition: 300ms;
}

.reverse { 
    transform: translateY(50%) rotate(90deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866) !important;
    margin-left: -155px;
    margin-right: -35px;
    margin-top: -90px;
}

.triangle {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transform: translateY(50%) rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866);
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.triangle:before, .triangle:after {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: '';
    background: gray;
}
.triangle:before {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 20% 53%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%)
    skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(-24%);
}
.triangle:after {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 53% 20%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%)
    skewX(-30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(24%);
}

.triangle:hover:before, .triangle:hover:after { 
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: @lampa, был бы идеальный способ. Уже было ручки потёр, чтоб добавить в коллекцию, но к моему удивлению, оказалось, что в Opera - работает с багом, Chrome и Safari работает с большим багом, про осла молчу. Обидно :(

Comment: @Deonis это наверно я скриворучил, тут всё ок: http://dabblet.com/gist/4589858

Answer (score 3):

Не всё так просто. Я ж так понимаю, что вы хотите и такой же эффект для менюшки? Там используется [карт-изображений](http://htmlbook.ru/html/map) в связке с элементами списка навигации, плюс jQuery для создания эффекта. Для того, чтоб понять работу всего этого, возмите всё, что находиться внутри тэга "**nav**" (*включая и его*) и разберите файл scripts.js: всё, что касается элемента **$('nav')** и **$('map[name=nav1] area')**.

---

P.S. Вытащил вам всё, что необходимо, кроме cufon (*с шрифтами сами разберетесь*). [Работу смотрите тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/FRYKE/), не забудьте про подключенный плагин в "External Resources".

Answer (score 1):

Если не сильно заморачиваться, то можно сделать [так](http://jsfiddle.net/X8ASd/). там это реализовано через [map](http://htmlbook.ru/html/map)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь есть треугольник на `CSS`. Может, вам пригодится [Геометрические фигуры на `CSS`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/)

Answer (score -1):

А в чем проблема там разобратся? Там список из блоков абсолютного позиционирования, в которых фоном картинка, для не парных нижняя(точнне блок порзрачный с нижним треугольником) для парных верхняя. При наведении меняется прознрачность блока hoverIn при уходе с блока меняется прозрачность hoverOut.

Comment: там через map сделано, а не блоками абсолютного позиционирования

Comment: :) внимательнее будте. Там блоки в списке, map та только для нажатия а вот эти все подсветки сделаны как я написал